# How do I specify specific data from an API?

Tags: api, iframe, shopify, steam, steam-web-api

I am attempting to extract specific data from the Steam API so far I have been able to filter the results, here is an example;

https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=218620&filters=metacritic

Which gives me;

```
{"218620":
  {"success":true,
   "data":
     {"metacritic": 
       {"score":79,"url":"https:\/\/www.metacritic.com\/game\/pc\/payday-2?ftag=MCD-06-10aaa1f"}
     }
  }
}
```

However, what I want is just the numerical score, so in this instance, it would just display '79'.

I am presenting the data using an iframe which is why it needs to call the specific value. If anyone has any suggestions about how I can do this or maybe offer up an alternative way to parse the data.

My coding skills are limited so this might seem like a basic question or a rather rudimentary way to extract the data so apologies in advance. I am also adding the code to Shopify which is PHP based if that helps.

I know https://steamspy.com/api.php have their own API which offers similar data would it be easier to collect it from there instead of directly from the Steam Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you get is in [JSON format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). JSON is designed for easy data access.

You did not specify your programming language and I have no experience with shopify. So here it is in Javascript. Try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/750nugwf/).

```
const jsonObject = {
  "218620":
    {"success":true,
      "data":
        {"metacritic":
            {"score":79,"url":"https:\/\/www.metacritic.com\/game\/pc\/payday-2?ftag=MCD-06-10aaa1f"}
        }
    }
};

const metacriticScore = jsonObject["218620"].data.metacritic.score;
console.log(metacriticScore);
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer this, I have since paid someone to write a script for me and integrate it into my website.